# ElasticSearch NEST C# - how to set up Number format pattern using annotations?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, annotations, nest, elastic-stack

Is there anyway to set up the Number format by Annotation in POCO class or any other way in C#?

I normally have to go into Kibana and set it manually in Management > Index Patterns > Format as the picture below.

[image]

And I was wondering if I couldn't do it by setting a parameter anywhere in my code using NEST. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Number format is a Kibana only setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-formatters-numeric.html) that determines how to format a number for visual display; there is no [number](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) format in Elasticsearch and hence none in NEST.

Comment: Thanks for the answer